# dataframe con valores numéricos y otros caracteres en la misma columna

Tags: r, dataframe

data<-read.csv(%%%), deberían ser solo valores numéricos para todas las filas, pero, tiene otros caracteres como letras... me gustaría dejar todas las filas, que solo contienen números en un nuevo dataframe(data_2) y las filas "erroneas en otro"(data_3). Saludos

Comment: Hola @Diego Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Para poder ofrecerte una respuesta, necesitamos que tu pregunta sea clara, incluir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que nos ayude a entender mejor tu problema. Te invito a que revises las recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu pregunta existen varios consideraciones que estoy asumiendo, las cuales son :

1.-Que existen mas de una columna dentro de tu Data.frame

2.-Que te interesa borrar todas aquellas filas que en cualquier columna cuente con una letra sin importar que otra columna solo sea numérico.

En base a estos dos supuestos es la solución que propongo es esta

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)


  #Creamos un data.frame con datos aleatorios por columna que pueda tener letras o no
  prueba<-data.frame(columna1=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,"A","B","C"),100,replace = TRUE),
       columna2=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,"A","B","C"),100,replace = TRUE),
       columna3=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,"A","B","C"),100,replace = TRUE))

  #Estructura del data.frame
  str(prueba)

  #Todas las filas son de tipo caracter
  mat_num<-data.frame(apply(prueba,c(1,2),function(x) !is.na(as.numeric(x))))

  #Dejamos solo una columna que marque si alguna fila tiene Letras
  fila_numerico<-mat_num %>% mutate(marca=(!(columna1==FALSE|columna2==FALSE | 
                               columna3==FALSE)))

  #Revisamos si quedan numeros
  summary(apply(numerico,c(1,2),as.numeric))

        columna1        columna2        columna3   
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.00  
1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:1.50  
Median :4.000   Median :3.000   Median :3.00  
Mean   :3.696   Mean   :3.739   Mean   :3.13  
3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:5.500   3rd Qu.:5.00  
Max.   :6.000   Max.   :6.000   Max.   :6.00
```

Aquí asumo que se tienen tres columnas , pero si puede cambiar en base al numero total de columnas que tenga

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación sería leer los datos como `character` inicialmente y en un vector nuevo coercionarlos a numérico. De esta forma los datos que sean sólo números tendrán un valor numérico y los que hayan contenido letras serán valor `NA`. Luego sólo es cuestión de hacer filtro.

```r
data <- read.csv("data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mivector <- as.numeric(data$columna)

# Los buenos
data_2 <- data[!is.na(mivector),]

#Los erróneos
data_3 <- data[is.na(mivector),]
```

Comment: gracias, me sirve esto